# restricting zero is not working for popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to restrict zero and dot for a field and it is working, But when the field is in pop up then the below code is not working.

```
<script>
  $('#name').keypress(function(e){ 
       if (this.selectionStart == 0 && e.which == 48 || this.selectionStart == 0 && e.which == 46 ){
          return false;
       }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: brackets help with boolean logic `this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46)`

Comment: Can you add relevant HTML/JS for the popup?

Comment: @NisargShah I am working on it

Comment: How many DOM nodes do you have with that same id (`#name`)?

Comment: @NisargShah http://jsfiddle.net/hcyj3q6q/397/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your modal's DOM is generated dynamically on click event, `$('.abc').keypress` doesn't bind to it (because the modal's DOM doesn't exist yet).

You could make use of event bubbling in such cases. In your case, you could declare the event handler like:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.abc', function(e){ 
   if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46) ){
      return false;
   }
});
```

This means all `keypress` events on an element with `.abc` will bubble up to the document, and the event handler will be triggered.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcyj3q6q/398/

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching click event on dynamically inserted element. For this

So instead of...

```
$(document).keypress('.abc', function(e){ 
   if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46) ){
      return false;
   }
});
```

You can write...

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.abc', function(e){ 
   if (this.selectionStart == 0 && (e.which == 48 || e.which == 46) ){
      return false;
   }
});
```

See this to know more [How to add event on dynamically inserted HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this(Javascript)

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode == 48 || charCode == 46 
           )
             return false;

          return true;
       }
```

here I have created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/8qde7gnk/2/